# Как правильно сделать sql запрос?

Tags: php, sql

Нужно что бы к каждой записи в блоге, отображались комментарии, оставленные непосредственно для записи.

Есть две таблицы, одна с постами,другая с комментариями. Я пытаюсь выполнить следующий запрос, где :id это $_GET[id]

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id=:id';
```

В принципе запрос работает, но проблема в том, что у меня записи в таблице постов начинаются с id 500, а комменты с id 17) Мой запрос выполняется только в том случае, если я сам руками поменяю id 17 на 500.

Возможно стоит воспользоваться джоинами? Хотя я тоже не понимаю, по каким столбцам объединять нужно.

Comment: Как вы определяете, что комментарий относится к определенной записи? Теоретически у вас в таблице "comments" должен бить столбец с айди записи, например "post_id". В запросе вам уже нужно указывать комментарии, к какой записи вам нужно, например `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id=:id';` - в таком случае запрос вернет вам все комментарии к определенной записи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таблице с комментариями должен быть столбец, содержащий id поста, к которому относится комментарий. Назовём его к примеру pID, тогда запрос будет следующий:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE pID=:id';
```

Результат - все комментарии, которые относятся к этому посту.

*Соответственно при добавлении комментария к посту, не забываем добавить ID именно этого поста в столбец pID*